# AWS ELB(ALB) rule check SSL expiry

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb, aws-certificate-manager

We had set up a common ALB as a single point of entry to all systems, We wanted to drop traffic at ALB when the SSL cert was not renewed(expired) by the individual system teams.

We have a 3rd part DDOS services that have automatic cert updates and it reflects the cert as valid but not the ALB Cert as the cert was not updated.

Internet -> DDOS services -> ALB -> Systems

I wonder if there's a way to deny traffic if the SSL cert is expired?

Comment: Maybe run a Lambda function periodically to check the cert status, and edit the routing rules if it has expired?

Comment: Hi Desmond, did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AWS config rule for the `AWS_CERTIFICATE_EXPIRATION_CHECK` event that triggers an SNS topic when the cert has expired (0 days to expiration).

The SNS topic can trigger a lambda function which removes/alters the security group rule that allows traffic from the security group associated with the ALB.